# creating a pure javascript based video player

Tags: javascript, components, video-streaming

can anyone tell me if we can create a video player purely in javascript? if yes then please suggest some guidelines and process like how will the buffering and streaming be achieved? using ajax in this case? is there any way to read local video files using javascript? etc.

NOTE: I am not talking about HTML 5.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Sure it is.](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsonvid-pure-javascript-video-player)**

But just because you can... doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 2):

It has been done before by loading a bunch of base64 encoded jpeg frames embedded in json through ajax. Makes browsers weep but fun to experiment with nonetheless.

http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/jsvideo/test1.php

Could be improved upon by streaming frames (setting up a buffer in js or dom to hold them), and getting around use of base64 encoding for loading frame images through ajax.